# Tooltip positioning C#

Tags: c#, .net, tooltip

I have a picturebox that has a mousehover event to show a tooltip based on the status of a service. This seems to be working, but it kind of just pops up where the mouse is and sometimes under the mouse, in the middle of the picture, which doesn't look right. I was reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511495.aspx#infotipsgl and it suggested to have the tooltip moved off to the side. This would be great, but I can't figure out how to move it.

ToolTip on toolTip1 is blank and on the mouseHover event I have tried using

```
toolTip.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox1, "Message text.");
```

and

```
toolTip.Show("Message text.", pictureBox1);
```

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752368.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
tooltip.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(50, 0, 0, 0);
tooltip.HorizontalOffset = 10;
tooltip.VerticalOffset = 20;
```

See [**Here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752368.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Placement is only available in WPF, not Winforms

Answer (score 0):

For windows forms you can use this overload of [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c85ff5s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. It allows you to set position offset relative to control that has tool tip.

In wpf as Ravi Patel has already pointed you to article simply us:

```
<ToolTip HorizontalOffset="10" 
               VerticalOffset="20" .../>
```

Comment: Hi Rafal, I ended up doing the same thing with a Windows Form. The Mouseover event seemed to work fine before I used the overloaded Show. After I added the positioning, it wouldn't hide. I added mouse leave events to hide it, but I was wondering if that's one of those things that needs to be done because of overloading Show, or if there's something else I can change.